# Why it's not possible to vote on comments in locked questions?

Tags: support, comment-voting, locked-questions

Topic says almost everything. If question is locked,

- voting on answers and comments in answers is allowed
- voting on question or comments in question is disallowed

Why is that? It's intuitive for locking that there will be no new comments or answers, but why is voting (only) partially disallowed?

Answer (score 4):

The actual behavior is that when a *post* is locked, comments on *that post* cannot be voted on.

If an answer to a question was locked, you'd notice that you cannot vote on the answer, nor on any of the comments to that answer. But you'd be free to vote on the other answers, the question, as well as comments on the question or the other answers.

When a question is locked, it's the only post that's locked. Since the individual answers are not automatically locked (since they are not necessarily the reason the question is locked), they do not need to have their votes or comments blocked.